# DevExpress GridControl ComboBoxEdit list item context menu command binding

Tags: binding, contextmenu, devexpress-wpf

I have this DevExpress GridControl that is dynamically created using a CellTemplateSelector.  One of the GridControl columns is defined by a DataTemplate that appears as follows:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NameComboColumnTemplate">
        <ContentControl>
            <dxg:GridColumn
                x:Name="GridColumnName"
                FieldName="{Binding Path=(dxci:DependencyObjectExtensions.DataContext).FieldName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                Header="{Binding Path=(dxci:DependencyObjectExtensions.DataContext).Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                Width="{Binding Path=(dxci:DependencyObjectExtensions.DataContext).Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit
                            IsTextEditable="False"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding RowData.Row.SelectedCylinderName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding RowData.Row.NameList, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="dxe:ComboBoxEditItem">
                                    <Setter Property="dxb:BarManager.DXContextMenu">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <dxb:PopupMenu>
                                                <dxb:BarButtonItem 
                                                    x:Name="BarButtonItemName"
                                                    Content="Delete"
                                                    Command="{Binding DeleteNameCommand}"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                            </dxb:PopupMenu>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

There exists a class called DataGridRow, that contains properties for ONE row of GridControl data.  This class also contains a command defined as

```
    public ICommand DeleteNameCommand => new DelegateCommand<object>(obj => DeleteName(obj));

    private void DeleteName(object obj)
    {
        // the obj parametercontains the text present on the ComboBoxEdit list item that was
        //  right-clicked to display the context menu.

        // Delete the name from the list here
    }
```

As shown above, the ComboBoxEdit **SelectedItem** and **ItemsSource** properties are bound to DataGridRow properties accessed via the **RowData.Row** property, and the **DeleteNameCommand** is also accessible via the **RowData.Row** property.

When the user clicks the ComboBoxEdit down-arrow, the list of Names is displayed, and when the user right-clicks a list name, the context menu is displayed. Since the PopupMenu/BarButtonItem is not part of the Visual Tree, how would I bind the BarButtonItem **Command** property to the RowData.Row property accessed in the ComboBoxEdit? ... and how could I pass the text of the ComboBoxEdit list item that was right-clicked as the value of the **CommandParameter**?

Any pointers to the right direction are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK ... after days of trying to figure this out, the great people at DevExpress were able to provide me with a solution.  My apologies for posting the question as I did not expect (my bad) to get a solution so quickly (I asked them yesterday afternoon), but I thought it useful to inform the community of the solution.

The ComboBoxEdit editor data context is accessible via

**(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).DataContext**

and to access the associated **RowData.Row** property, which itself contains the properties usable for each row **column**, is accessible via

**(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).DataContext.RowData.Row**

SO, it follows that the PopupMenu/BarButtonItem **Command** can be bound to the DeleteNameCommand contained in the DataGridRow class, which itself is accessible via RowData.Row by specifying the following:

**Command="{Binding Path=(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).DataContext.RowData.Row.DeleteNameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"**

... and the text of the ComboBoxEdit list item that was right-clicked is available to pass as the value for CommandParameter via the following declaration:

**CommandParameter="{Binding}"**

... and there was much rejoicing :-)